# AJV - How to add custom Error messages in Javascrip

Tags: javascript, ajv

I am using AJV for custom validation. I want to change the error message as well while validate,
I am using  -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.11.0/ajv.min.js"></script>

var imageValidation = {
    required: ['name', 'url', 'source','tags'],
    properties: {
      name: {type: 'string'},
      url: {
        type: 'string', 
        pattern: "(^s3\:\/\/.+(jpeg|JPEG|jpg|JPG)$)",
        errorMessage: {
            type:'must be a string',
            pattern: "Image extension should match with jpeg, JPEG, jpg, JPG format"
        }
        // messages: {
        //     pattern: 'Image extention should match with jpeg, JPEG, jpg, JPG format'
        // }
        // message: "Image extention should match with jpeg, JPEG, jpg, JPG format"
      },
      source: {type: 'string'},
      tags: {type: 'array'}
    }
    allRequired: true
};
```

I am getting each and every time default error message provided by AJV.  I am excepting - My Error message should be -

Image extension should match with jpeg, JPEG, jpg, JPG format

Also tried with message attributes. Same issue. Am I doing something wrong, Or do I need to import some scripts ?

Answer (score 4):

i think you should use [ajv-errors](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-errors) package to make custom error messages

Comment: I can't do npm install ajv-errors . Is that any other way to add ajv-errors inside <script> tags

Comment: i don't know if it works or not  but use this link and check if it works:
[ https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ajv-errors@1.0.1/index.min.js ]
if not you can download package from github page and use it in your project staticly
hope it woks!

Comment: No bro. Not working. Thanks you, for your quick response.

Comment: This may help https://github.com/rofrol/ajv-regexp-errormessage-example